# Switch between users in a packaged app. How?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-chrome-app

I have some doubts regrading the chrome identity API.

If I want to login to the application with a different user I would have to change the "chrome login" (not the "gmail login" temporarilly stored in the browser)

In a web app using gapi.auth.authorize with immediate mode set to false should prompt for user credentials.

With a packaged app how can I switch between users without having to change the chrome user?

Thanks

PS: Seams there is a sample "Tasks app using GAPI" might help
https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/tasks

PS2: In the sample chrome.identity.getAuthToken is also used so the question still stands...

Answer (score 1):

This feature is tracked in Issue 258515: [Support multiple logins for Chrome Identity API](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=258515)

You can 'star' the issue to receive email updates on its activity.

Comment: No need to thank him -- that's what accepting answers and upvotes are for!